# .NET Core 3.1 console app is printing all trace logs regardless of log level

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am working my way through "C# 8.0 and .NET Core 3.0" by Mark Price and my logging demonstration project is not behaving the way the book suggests. The demo shows how to change the log level (error, warning, info, verbose) to filter logs. Instead of omitting logs at a lower level than desired, all of the logs are getting printed with a boolean value at the end: true if the log is within the printable level, false if it is below.

For example, with the log level set to `Warning`, when I run `dotnet run --configuration Release` the application should log

```
Trace error
Trace warning
```

instead, it logs

```
Trace error: True
Trace warning: True
Trace info: False
Trace verbose: False
```

Here is my main file:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace Instrumenting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Write to a text file in the project folder
            Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(File.CreateText("log.txt")));
            // Text writer is buffered, so this option calls Flush() on all listeners after writing
            Trace.AutoFlush = true;
            // Debug.WriteLine("Debug says, I am watching!");
            // Trace.WriteLine("Trace says, I am watching!");

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
            var ts = new TraceSwitch(displayName: "PacktSwitch", description: "This switch is set via a JSON config.");
            configuration.GetSection("PacktSwitch").Bind(ts);
            Trace.WriteLine(ts.TraceError, "Trace error");
            Trace.WriteLine(ts.TraceWarning, "Trace warning");
            Trace.WriteLine(ts.TraceInfo, "Trace info");
            Trace.WriteLine(ts.TraceVerbose, "Trace verbose");
        }
    }
}
```

and my csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and appsettings.json, which designates the log level

```
{
    "PacktSwitch": {
        "Level": "Warning"
    }
}
```

What is causing this, and how do I get it to log normally?

Comment: You're calling `Trace.WriteLine(object, string)`, with the first parameter being a boxed `bool` and the second the category name, explaining your output. You probably intended to call `Trace.WriteLineIf(bool, string)` instead. Note that `Trace` is a rather old-fashioned, clunky, not to mention limited logging framework; even when it was first conceived there were better alternatives (`log4net`, `NLog`, probably more). As long as you're using `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` already, consider using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` as well.

Comment: That is the problem! I re-read the code snippet in the book over and over and glided right over those "If"s every time. Thanks! And yeah, I'm only using Trace here because it's what the book uses for the demo. I don't think it's what my company uses. Thank you!